# What does the driver.execute_script("window.stop();") do in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

```
def scrape_scholar(keyword) :
    try :
        url = 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=2017&q=&btnG='
        option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("./UI/chromedriver", options=option)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2000)
        driver.get(url)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="gs_hdr_frm"]/div[1]/input')))
        driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
```

I don't know the role of the last instruction in python scraping.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code. And javascript command `window.stop()` stops a page load.
This command basically is used when page is loading for a long time, because it has many elements or huge ajax communications.

Anyways, you can use this command when stop a page loading before a certain time, in python.

Hope to be helpful for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.stop();
```

is basically to stop a page loading.

Also that's a JS command, so for that you have used `execute_script`.

In `Python-Selenium`, `execute_script` is a way to execute Javascript commands.

It basically depends on your use case, whether to use `driver.execute_script("window.stop();")` or other commands.